# Format with leading zeros in Erlang

Tags: erlang, string-formatting

I would like to return the local time as string but with leading zeros. I tried this:

```
{{Year, Month, Day}, {Hour, Minute, Second}} = erlang:localtime().
DateAsString = io_lib:format("~2.10.0B~2.10.0B~4.10.0B~2.10.0B~2.10.0B~2.10.0B", 
           [Month, Day, Year, Hour, Minute, Second]).
```

But if some of the components is one digit, the returned string is:

```
[["0",57],"29","2011","17","33","34"]
```

The current month `9` is printed as `["0",57]`.

Please, help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
1> lists:flatten([["0",57],"29","2011","17","33","34"]).
"09292011173334"
```

`io_lib:format/2` (and it's companion `io:format/2`) actually returns a deep IO list. Such a list is printable and can be sent on a socket or written to a file just as a flat string, but is more efficient to produce. Flattening is often useless, because in all cases where the string will be printed or output to a file/socket it will automatically be flattened by Erlang.

Comment: Thanks. Flattening the list returns the correct string. I use the current time to build a filename. I only wonder where this `["0",57]` comes from? Thanks again.

Comment: 57 is the ASCII code for "9". Flattening is just forcing the formatted return value to a single string, so the whole thing gets interpreted as ASCII. Remember, in Erlang, normal strings are just arrays of integers. The `erl` environment has to guess how you want a given array of integers to be interpreted. It happens to have guessed wrong in your case, but really, it's doing the same thing.

Comment: A clarification to Adam's great answer is that io:format("~s", [DateAsString]) prints exactly what you are asking for.  (Also try io:format("~s", [["0", 57]]) to see that "09" and ["0", 57] are the same from an io point of view.)

Answer (score 3):

You want to be using something like this:

```
DateAsString = io_lib:format("~2..0w~2..0w~4..0w~2..0w~2..0w~2..0w", 
       [Month, Day, Year, Hour, Minute, Second]).
```

The more common `w` format modifier does the right thing here, what with base and such, so there's no need to use the more complex `B` modifier. `2..0` says "2 characters wide, zero padded, no precision specified." We don't need precision here, since we're dealing with integers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The `~2..0w` actually returns the same result.